# Convert System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken to System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken in c#

Tags: c#, .net, security, jwt, identity

Earlier in our .Net application we were using ACS service for validating user identity but now we are using OKTA authentication.  In ACS we were getting **SecurityToken** and from OKTA we are now getting **JwtSecurityToken**.

But to support our legacy application I need to convert **JwtSecurityToken** to **SecurityToken** and pass the **SecurityToken** in rest of application.  So,Can we convert convert **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken** to **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken**.  If not then how to solve this problem.

Comment: `JwtSecurityToken : SecurityToken`.

Comment: My application is  using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken that i am unable convert to JwtSecurityToken. Can we do that. ?

Comment: Hi Mentors.. I have updated the question. Need your valuable suggestions.